# Scheme: do these two lists have identical memory representations?

Tags: list, memory, scheme, representation

I'm using R5RS standart of Scheme language.

Please have a look at these two objects:

1. `(1 (2 . 3))`
2. `(1 2 . 3)`

Do they have the same memory representations? Like this (A):
[image]

Or the first one is different? Like this (B):[image]

So... What is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're different. The first list is constructed like this, corresponding to the "B" figure:

```
(cons 1
      (cons (cons 2 3)
            '()))

> '(1 (2 . 3))
```

Whereas the second list structure is constructed like this, which corresponds to the "A" figure:

```
(cons 1
      (cons 2 3))

> '(1 2 . 3)
```

Also notice that the second one is not a *proper list* (meaning: a list that ends with `null`).

Comment: Thanks for fine explanation :)